# How to sort two table viewer columns if value in one column is equal with other one?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have used Vogella tutorial to create a tableviewer in a plugin view and to sort the columns. 
The problem is that currently the sorting is done based on one column. If the first name is the same I will like to sort the last name alphabetically :

Example

```
Unsorted :

Col 1  Col 2
John Smith
John A

Sorted:

Col1 Col2
John A
John Smith
```

Used code:

```
   package de.vogella.jface.tableviewer.sorter;

import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerComparator;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;

import de.vogella.jface.tableviewer.model.Person;

public class MyViewerComparator extends ViewerComparator {
  private int propertyIndex;
  private static final int DESCENDING = 1;
  private int direction = DESCENDING;

  public MyViewerComparator() {
    this.propertyIndex = 0;
    direction = DESCENDING;
  }

  public int getDirection() {
    return direction == 1 ? SWT.DOWN : SWT.UP;
  }

  public void setColumn(int column) {
    if (column == this.propertyIndex) {
      // Same column as last sort; toggle the direction
      direction = 1 - direction;
    } else {
      // New column; do an ascending sort
      this.propertyIndex = column;
      direction = DESCENDING;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public int compare(Viewer viewer, Object e1, Object e2) {
    Person p1 = (Person) e1;
    Person p2 = (Person) e2;
    int rc = 0;
    switch (propertyIndex) {
    case 0:
      rc = p1.getFirstName().compareTo(p2.getFirstName());
      break;
    case 1:
      rc = p1.getLastName().compareTo(p2.getLastName());
      break;
    case 2:
      rc = p1.getGender().compareTo(p2.getGender());
      break;
    case 3:
      if (p1.isMarried() == p2.isMarried()) {
        rc = 0;
      } else
        rc = (p1.isMarried() ? 1 : -1);
      break;
    default:
      rc = 0;
    }
    // If descending order, flip the direction
    if (direction == DESCENDING) {
      rc = -rc;
    }
    return rc;
  }

}
```

I know compareTo returns 0 when the compared elements are equal, but I don't know how to keep the comparison for one column and the compare the second column elements based on first column sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
public int compare(Viewer viewer, Object e1, Object e2) {

Person p1 = (Person) e1;
Person p2 = (Person) e2;
int rc = 0;

if(!p1.getFirstName().equals(p2.getFirstName())) {
    rc = p1.getFirstName().compareTo(p2.getFirstName());
}else if(!p1.getLastName().equals(p2.getLastName())) {
    rc = p1.getLastName().compareTo(p2.getLastName());
}else if(!p1.getGender().equals(p2.getGender())) {
    rc = p1.getGender().compareTo(p2.getGender());
}else if(!p1.isMArried==p2.isMarried) {
    rc = (p1.isMarried() ? 1 : -1);
}else rc=0;

return rc;
}
```